# @xmlSchema annotation use with jaxb

Tags: xml, schema, annotations, jaxb

I can't get to show in a xml file all the parameters configured with the @xmlSchema annotation at package level. For example, if I set:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (               
    xmlns = { 
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "com", 
                     namespaceURI="http://es.indra.transporte.common"),

            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix = "xsi",
                     namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),

            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix = "ns2",
                     namespaceURI="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration"),             
           },    
    location = "http://es.indra.transporte.configuration StationNetwork.xsd",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED        
)
package es.indra.transporte.central.thalesinterface.common.beans;
```

I expect to see something like:

```
<stationNetwork xmlns:ns2="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration"
                xmlns:com="http://es.indra.transporte.common"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration StationNetwork.xsd">
```

but I get the following output:

```
<stationNetwork xmlns:com="http://es.indra.transporte.common">
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can write out a schema location as follows:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://es.indra.transporte.configuration StationNetwork.xsd");
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
```

Running the following code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(StationNetwork.class);

        StationNetwork root = new StationNetwork();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://es.indra.transporte.configuration StationNetwork.xsd");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output - [Metro (JAXB RI)](http://jaxb.java.net/)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<stationNetwork 
    xmlns:com="http://es.indra.transporte.common"  
    xmlns:ns2="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration"     
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration StationNetwork.xsd"/>
```

**Output - [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stationNetwork 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration StationNetwork.xsd" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://es.indra.transporte.configuration" 
    xmlns:com="http://es.indra.transporte.common" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Comment: How would I do set the xmlns on the root node with annotations?  I return from my @Get method with Response.ok(entity).build(), and I'm not using the marshaller directly at all.