# JAXB @XmlSchema location ignored

Tags: java, xml, groovy, jaxb

I am trying to generate a sitemap.xml using JAXB, and the location attribute is being ignored (I want to generate the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute on my root element).

I want to generate an xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ns3:urlset 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <urls>
        <loc>http://domain.com</loc>
    </urls>
    <urls>
        <loc>http://domain.com/test</loc>
    </urls>
</ns3:urlset>
```

I have seen other questions: 
[@xmlSchema annotation use with jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863786/xmlschema-annotation-use-with-jaxb) and [How to generate the correct sitemap namespace using JAXB and Spring @ResponseBody in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402575/how-to-generate-the-correct-sitemap-namespace-using-jaxb-and-spring-responsebod)

But neither of these solve the problem I am experiencing with the **annotation**.

I have the following package-info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    xmlns = @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs( prefix = "xsi", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ),
    location = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED
)
package com.domain.site.sitemap
```

However, my unit test:

```
@Test public void createXmlObject(){
    List urls = [ "test1", "test2", "test3" ]
    Sitemap map = new Sitemap( urls )
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Sitemap )
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller()
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true)
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(map, System.out)
}
```

generates a root element as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns3="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

If I update the test to explicitly set the location using `jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "location..")` then it will get populated - but I want to understand why it is not working with the annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [specification](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html#location()):

> Note to implementor [...]
>
> However, the schema generator is allowed to
>   use a different value in the schemaLocation attribute (**including not
>   generating such attribute**), for example so that the user can specify a
>   local copy of the resource through the command line interface.

So it's up to the implementation provider if location is generated or not.

Comment: Thanks - I did spot that in the docs, but as my test is just using plain JAXB (JAXBContenxt creates a javax.xml.bind.Marshaller) I was hoping they would have implemented it - I assumes this means not though?

Comment: Seems like `no`. Tried to drill into the sources but it was taking too much time.